# HIVE - SQL insert record

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

In HIVE SQL , i ran same query in two different cloudera version. Cloudera VM 5.10 is not causing any issue. But another version cloudera -CDH-5.1.0-1.cdh5.1.0.p0.53 is throwing error.

```
hive> select * from t;
OK
Time taken: 1.803 seconds
hive> insert into table t values (1);
NoViableAltException(26@[])
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser_SelectClauseParser.selectClause(HiveParser_SelectClauseParser.java:713)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.selectClause(HiveParser.java:35992)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.regular_body(HiveParser.java:33510)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.queryStatement(HiveParser.java:33389)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.queryStatementExpression(HiveParser.java:33169)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.execStatement(HiveParser.java:1284)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.statement(HiveParser.java:983)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseDriver.parse(ParseDriver.java:190)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:434)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:352)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compileInternal(Driver.java:995)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1038)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:931)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:921)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:268)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:220)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:790)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:684)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:623)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)
FAILED: ParseException line 1:20 cannot recognize input near 'values' '(' '1' in select clause
hive>
```

Any idea? which version have to choose for my studies. Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In older versions of CDH like CDH-5.1 insert record is not supported but in new versions of CDH it is supported feature.
So instead of trying insert into values,try with Load data statement

If your file is in Local then

```
hive> LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '<local-path-tofile>' INTO TABLE t;
```

If your file is in HDFS then

```
hive> LOAD DATA INPATH 'hdfs_file_or_directory_path'  INTO TABLE t;
```

For more details refer to:-
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/GettingStarted#GettingStarted-DMLOperations

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying is right, make sure you have one column in your table. if you multiple columns you need have the values for all the fields. checkout the below image [image]

The version I tried in :

```
[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ hadoop version
Hadoop 2.6.0-cdh5.5.0
Subversion http://github.com/cloudera/hadoop -r fd21232cef7b8c1f536965897ce20f50b83ee7b2
Compiled by jenkins on 2015-11-09T20:37Z
Compiled with protoc 2.5.0
From source with checksum 98e07176d1787150a6a9c087627562c
This command was run using /usr/jars/hadoop-common-2.6.0-cdh5.5.0.jar
```

Comment: the same command i tried in my VM. see below `hive> desc t;
OK
id                      int                     None
Time taken: 0.974 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
hive> insert into table t values (12);
NoViableAltException(26@[])
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser_SelectClauseParser.selectClause(HiveParser_SelectClauseParser.java:713)           
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)
FAILED: ParseException line 1:20 cannot recognize input near 'values' '(' '12' in select clause
hive>`

Comment: Can you add the table description to the table?

Comment: i couldn't paste decribe table result. since it is tool long

Comment: LastAccessTime:         UNKNOWN
Protect Mode:           None
Retention:              0
Location:               hdfs://hadoopmasters:8020/user/hive/warehouse/t
Table Type:             MANAGED_TABLE

Comment: Table Parameters:
        transient_lastDdlTime   1519401315\
# Storage Information
SerDe Library:          org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe
InputFormat:            org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat
OutputFormat:           org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputForm

Comment: Compressed:             No
Num Buckets:            -1
Bucket Columns:         []
Sort Columns:           []
Storage Desc Params:
        serialization.format    1
Time taken: 0.111 seconds, Fetched: 26 row(s)

Comment: posted with different comment section @roh

Comment: Please remove it from comments and add it as a code block in question. Your comments are not at all clear.

Comment: posted. can you please check

Answer (score 0):

@roh

```
 hive> describe formatted t;
    OK
    # col_name              data_type               comment
    id                      int                     None
    # Detailed Table Information
    Database:               default
    Owner:                  learnhadoop
    CreateTime:             Fri Feb 23 21:25:15 IST 2018
    LastAccessTime:         UNKNOWN
    Protect Mode:           None
    Retention:              0
    Location:               hdfs://hadoopmasters:8020/user/hive/warehouse/t
    Table Type:             MANAGED_TABLE
    Table Parameters:
            transient_lastDdlTime   1519401315\
    # Storage Information
    SerDe Library:          org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe
    InputFormat:            org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat
    OutputFormat:           org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputForm                                                                             at
    Compressed:             No
    Num Buckets:            -1
    Bucket Columns:         []
    Sort Columns:           []
    Storage Desc Params:
            serialization.format    1
    Time taken: 0.111 seconds, Fetched: 26 row(s)
    hive>
```